# Recover iPhone from an older iCloud backup

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, data-recovery

There's some data I want to recover I've lost this morning due to an accidental synchronization. Unfortunately, it made a new backup, so recovering the lost files via iCloud doesn't seem possible anymore. So, is it possible to recover an iPhone from an older backup in iCloud?

Btw., there's no backup on my Mac as I've made a clean reinstallation. So, the only way to recover the lost files is by using iCloud.

Comment: Do you have a Time Machine backup of your Mac?

Comment: Yes, I made a complete backup before I reinstalled it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see your available backups in iCloud when you go in your iPhone to Settings > your name > iCloud > Manage Storage > Backups. That’s all you have in iCloud.

If none of these backups store the data you need, then the only hope can be in the Time Machine backup before the reinstallation in case you backed up your iPhone in iTunes/Music app. In that case you may want to restore content of this directory while iTunes is not running:
`/Users/[your user]/Library/Application Support/Mobile Sync`
Once done, you can start iTunes and see restored backups in Settings and the tab with devices.